# Button with lost focus using PerspectiveTrasnform

Tags: javafx-8, effects

Well, I make a Pane based on an example of JavaFX samples (Display Shelf), I put Panes with Labels, Buttons, ComboBox, TableView where's the ImageView. It is working, when I click on Pane, it does the animation correctly, but the buttons that I put in vertical on Right of Pane, receive the focus out of where they are. When I move the mouse button, nothing happens, but if I move the mouse to down of it, I can click in the button that so reveice the focus. The local where I have to move the mouse to button to receive the focus is increasingly far (down) if the button is below the other.

I'm using the Perspective Transform of JavaEX and all is in JavaFX Samples, just changed some params of size (width and height). This effect may be interfering in focus? Or can be another problem? If anyone already had this problem please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a code example?

Comment: Of course! I'm not with my computer now, but I will do it as soon as possible.